# Flutter remove bottom padding container

Tags: flutter, containers, padding

I created a custom dialogBox but when I add 2 buttons at the bottom I still have a padding, how can I remove it?

This is my code

```
  contentBox(context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    widget.title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Text(
                    widget.descriptions,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Reject'),
                    onPressed: () => null,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text('Approve'),
                    onPressed: () => null,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result :

[image]

PS: if there are optimizations, please tell me as I'm beginning in flutter

Comment: You mean the padding after the buttons?

Comment: @EhsanAskari yes

Comment: wrap them inside a Expanded widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is because `RaisedButton` have a fixed height. Wrap the `RaisedButton` inside a `Container` widget and give it a height value. Like this and it should be fine**

```
Expanded(
    child: Container(
      height: 48,
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Reject'),
        onPressed: () => null,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Do this for both of your buttons
This is the output:

[image]

Also if you want to create an alert box it is better to use flutter build in widgets like `AlertDialog` if you want iOS styled alert box then you can use `CupertinoAlertDialog`

`AlertDialog`'s are very well explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75CsnyRXf5I)

Answer (score 1):

**RaisedButton have some default padding, so you need to create a custom button like this :**

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
      const CustomButton({
        Key key,
        this.backgroundColor,
        this.child,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      final child;
      final Color backgroundColor;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 40,
          child: Material(
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Now use it in your code, replace your row with this**

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
     child: CustomButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      child: Text('Reject'),
     ),
    ),
    Expanded(
     child: CustomButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      child: Text('Approve'),
     ),
    ),
   ],
 ),
```

Result :
[image]